# Duplicate auxiliary verbs in a sentence (may we / should we delete the second?)

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, ellipses, coordinating-conjunctions

What is a general rule for use of auxiliary verbs in sentence? Should we duplicate it or not?
For instance,

> It is available for every item and (***is***) used with . . .

Comment: this is more about the coordinating conjunction "and". You can leave out both "it" and "is"

Comment: As suggested in the above comment it is a question of how you structure the sentence. If you use and, you have to restate subject  (it) and verb (is used).

Comment: @Josh61, no, you do not. You can leave them both out.

Comment: See [***Conjunction Reduction***](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20conjunction%20reduction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence, *is* is the main verb in the first part, and is the auxiliary verb in the second part. This makes deleting the second *is* ungrammatical. So you have two options:

> It is available for every item and is used with …
>    It is available for every item and it is used with …

If *is* is the main verb in both parts, or the auxiliary verb in both parts, you can (optionally) delete its second use:

> It is available for every item and ready to use with no complicated set-up.
>   It is packaged with every item and used with …

The same rule applies to *has*; don't delete the second usage if it plays two different grammatical roles (i.e., main verb and auxiliary verb):

> *It has deadly venom and killed countless people.   (Wrong)
>   It has deadly venom and has killed countless people. (Correct)

ADDED: From the comments, some people perceive that in the OP's sentence, *used* is a past participle that is close enough to an adjective that *is* can be deleted. I perceive deleting it as ungrammatical.

There are three possible uses for *to be* as a verb form: an auxiliary verb signalling the passive voice, an auxiliary verb signalling a continuous tense, and the main verb. I don't believe you can use ellipsis if the verb plays two of these different roles. Consider the following sentences, all of which I perceive as ungrammatical:

> *He was incompetent and embezzling.
>   *He was incompetent and fired for that reason.
>   *He was embezzling and fired for that reason.

On the other hand, both the past participle and present participle can function as adjectives, and in this case you can use ellipsis to delete the verb. For example, I don't feel that there is anything wrong with the following sentence:

> The child was tired, hungry, and crying.

Comment: Could you provide a vetted grammar source for that? -- If you do, I'll up vote it. :)

Comment: That last set of examples is interesting, for *"It has deadly venom and (it) killed countless people"* would seem to be possible, and yet . . .

Comment: @F.E., having the sentence without the second _has_ is grammatical, but as you note it changes the structure. The second clause ends up being in the past tense, not the perfect, and therefore does not temporally parallel the first clause.

Comment: @Peter, I'm not sure I agree with you here. When _is_ clearly has different functions, I agree that deletion is not usually possible (though I think it does occur even there); but I think _used with_ in this case here is close enough to being a simple, true adjective (rather than part of a passive construction) that deletion works. At least, when I read it in my head, the version with deletion sounds as natural as the one without.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But is that a grammatical constraint on both coordinates? -- What is also interesting is that the example sentence seems to be more/completely acceptable with a comma: *"It has deadly venom, and killed countless people."*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The rule that PeterShor is talking about sounds familiar, but I've forgotten how that general grammatical rule is actually stated and don't remember all the caveats tied to it. And I'm too lazy to look it up--hopefully PeterShor will do all the hard work. :)

Comment: @F.E., I don't follow—is what a grammatical constraint on both coordinates? “It has deadly venom(,) and killed countless people” is fine; but the second clause cannot be interpreted as having a perfect-tense verb where the auxiliary (repeated from the first clause) has been omitted. Compare, “The moose was sighted several times and eventually killed by a car that hit it” (second clause is passive _was killed_ with omitted auxiliary) vs. “The moose was sighted several times and eventually killed the driver of a car that hit it” (second clause is active _killed_, no omitted auxiliary).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If your last example is shortened: *“The moose was sighted and killed the driver of a car."*--it doesn't feel right to me. The semantic roles played by "moose" in the two coordinates is different, and the shortened sentence doesn't allow the reader enough time to switch the roles smoothly, imo. Also, there is a grammatical rule about the usage of the auxiliary, on the constraints it's under, as to how it works in the two coordinates. Of course, if it's the same usage in both coordinates then usually no problem; but if not, then it's often unacceptable--but maybe not always.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet My last comment might be confusing, as I'm talking about two different issues in there. Sorry about that.

Comment: @F.E., I don’t have any problems with “The moose was sighted and killed the driver” (except inasmuch as the shortening makes it seem like there’s a causal relationship between the verbs, which of course there isn’t—or alternatively inasmuch as it simply states that the moose is able to see). It’s no different than “He was fired and spent two years unemployed” or “She was tenured and taught philosophy at Oxford”, for example, and I can’t find anything wrong with those …

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In your first example *"He was fired and spent two years unemployed"*, the subject's semantic roles in the two coordinates are somewhat similar in that "he" doesn't have a dynamic agentive role in either; also, "was spent" isn't meaningful for the 2nd coordinate. In your 2nd example,the context set up by the fact that she was tenured sorta sets the reader up to interpret that "she" was the one doing the teaching. But in *"The moose was sighted twice and killed the driver”*, there's a drastic change in semantic roles in a very short interval--that's the problem, imo.

Comment: Hmmm, still no vetted grammar source. Don't make me pull out my *CGEL* books (2002 and 1985). -- As to *"There are three possible uses for to be as a verb form:"*, well I'm seeing at least six uses: copula ***be***, progressive ***be***, passive ***be***, quasi-modal ***be***, motional ***be***, lexical ***be***. (2002 *CGEL*, page 113)

Comment: *"There are three possible uses for to be as a verb form: an auxiliary verb signalling the passive voice, an auxiliary verb signalling a continuous tense, and the main verb. I don't believe you can use ellipsis if the verb plays two of these different roles."* -- that's not quite right, for there's *"He was living in the Latin Quarter and thought to have AIDS"* which has a coordination of progressive and passive constructions. (2002 *CGEL*, page 1327). cc: @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: @Janus: You're right. I found *"Detectives identified a location where the suspect was living and believed to be storing the motorcycle."* I think that sounds much better than my example: *"He was embezzling and fired."*