# Verbs different forms in a same sentence

Tags: grammar, past-participles, present-participles

My question is related to the statement mentioned below. In first part after auxiliary verb "is" the main verb is present participle which is "increasing" while in the last part the verb is past participle "Used". Does it make sense? and how we can rephrase the sentence.

TOm pricing signal is "increasing" widely and "used" in different ways.

Comment: 'It is increasing quickly and becoming better known' and 'It is made in China and used mainly in the United States' show two totally acceptable deleted constructions (with the second '[it] is' omitted in each example). But this is not acceptable with one present and one past participle. 'It is increasing widely[,] and is used  in different ways' is grammatical (though one has to question how idiomatic putting two vastly different concepts into one sentence is).

Comment: If not a duplicate, addressed at [Duplicate auxiliary verbs in a sentence (may we / should we delete the second?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157198/duplicate-auxiliary-verbs-in-a-sentence/163235#163235)

Comment: *Tom pricing signal is* makes no sense. Do you mean ***Tom's*** *[possessive] pricing signal is* or ***the*** *Tom pricing signal is*?

Answer (score 0):

> **Tom pricing signal is  increasing widely  and  (it is ) used  in  different ways.**

The above sentence is absolutely grammatical.The first part of the sentence is in the present progressive  and the second part is in the simple present.The verb  **is**   is  applicable to  both  the clauses.

Comment: you mean to use the  ("it")  after 'and' or it is still fine without it?

Comment: @Shane. I think it is optional and understood.

Comment: okay Thanks. you mean this is true then, Tom pricing signal is increasing widely and used in different ways.